# React compound interest calculator Math.pow giving NaN?

Tags: reactjs

i'm just trying to make compound interest cal with react js but its giving me NaN as result im getting all thing but when i consolo.log Math.pow((1 + interest / time, time * years)) its giving me NaN please help.

```
const CompoundInterest = () => {
  const [principal, setPrincipal] = useState();
  const [years, setYears] = useState();
  const [interest, setInterest] = useState();
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  const calculate = () => {
    // A=p(1+(r/n))^(nt)
    const amount = principal * Math.pow((1 + interest / time, time * years));
    console.log((1 + interest / time, time * years));
    const result = amount - principal;

    setResult(result.toFixed(2));
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTime(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="annualCompoundCalculator">
        <form>
          <TextField
            label="What is the principal?"
            variant="outlined"
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setPrincipal(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            label="How many years?"
            variant="outlined"
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setYears(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            label="Annual Interest rate?"
            variant="outlined"
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setInterest(e.target.value / 100)}
          />
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">time</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={time}
            label="Age"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value={12}>Per Month</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={4}>Per 3 Month</MenuItem>
            {/* <MenuItem value={6}>Per 6 Month</MenuItem> */}
            <MenuItem value={1}>Per Year</MenuItem>
          </Select>
```

Comment: Share here what the values ​​of `interest` `time`  `years`

Comment: @HaimAbeles its input value

Comment: Of course, I mean to ask what they contain while you do the math on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is the all value
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEqSa.png

Answer (score 1):

in your `calculate` function

change `time` to `Number(time)`

Comment: bro that didnt worked

Comment: could you please tell what are the values for
 interest , time , years

in the console.log

Comment: i didnt gave second argument to math.pow! thats why it was not working

Answer (score 1):

The reason must be that one of the three variables `interest` `time` `years` is `null` when you try to do the calculation, so the calculation returns NaN because they are not numbers

Comment: Okay ill try to check value of those again but thank you !

Comment: i didnt gave second argument to math.pow! thats why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

```
  const calculate = () => {
    // A=p(1+(r/n))^(nt)
    const a = interest / time;
    const b = 1 + a;
    const c = time * years;
    const d = Math.pow(b, c);
    const amount = (principal * d).toFixed(2);
    const result = amount;

    setResult(result);
  };
```

Comment: @Shiva sai idk but in this function its worked